# Fuzzywuzzy - copy info associated with a row from one df to another using a match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fuzzywuzzy

My goal is to match address information based on 2 separate data frames. One data frame contains a unique value and the other dataframe does not. Id like to take the unique key from df1 and copy it to df2 based on how similar the fuzzy match is.

Here's an example:

```
df1 = 

index  address_df1           unique key     call #      Name        Sales amount
                      (value I want to copy)

1    123 nice road           Uniquekey1      11       jim bob             8
2    150  spring drive       Uniquekey2      151      jane doe            8213
3    240 happy lane          Uniquekey3      71       michael scott       909
4    80 sad parkway          Uniquekey4      1586     tracey jackson      109
5    122 big lane            Uniquekey5      161      lulu buzz           99
6    315 small pk            Uniquekey6      586      tinker bell         11
7    13  round rd ste 10     Uniquekey7      8601     jack ryan          681
8    97  square rd           Uniquekey8      66       peter paul         61968

df2 (*note address column in different place) =

index   cost center        country         address_df2  

1         1111              us              123 nice rd 
2         1111              us              97  square rd 
3         1112              us              13  round rd
4         1112              us              150  spring dr
```

I'd like the final data frame to look like this:

```
RESULT 
df3 (with unique key) =

index   cost center(df2)      country(df2)      address_df2         **unique key(from df1)**   fuzzy match %

1         1111                  us              123 nice rd            Uniquekey1               90%
2         1111                  us              97  square rd          Uniquekey8               90%
3         1112                  us              13  round rd           Uniquekey7               90%
4         1112                  us              150  spring dr         Uniquekey2               90%
```

I've tried:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process

THRESHOLD = 90

best_match = \
    df2['address_df2'].apply(lambda x: process.extractOne(x, df1['address_df1'],
                                                      score_cutoff=THRESHOLD))
```

Im able to find the matches using this code and its awesome! However, when I go to merge the two dataframes I cant get the address to match up. I think the data coming in from df1 isnt sorting or matching on the address together.

I've tried this code (below) to match the 2 dfs but again, the address's dont align. So what ends up happening is the unique id are incorrect.

```
df3 = pd.merge(df2, df1.set_index(best_match.apply(pd.Series)[2]),
               left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third items of the tuple returned by `extractOne` is the index label of the best match row of `df1`. So you can use `loc` to select the `unique key` column from `df1`.

```
# Prefer use thefuzz package
from thefuzz import process

THRESHOLD = 90

best_match = lambda x: process.extractOne(x, df1['address_df1'])
match = df2['address_df2'].apply(best_match).apply(pd.Series)

df2['unique key'] = df1.loc[match[2], 'unique key'] \
                       .mask(match[1].lt(THRESHOLD).values) \
                       .values
```

Output:

```
>>> df2
   cost center country     address_df2  unique key
1         1111      us     123 nice rd  Uniquekey1
2         1111      us    97 square rd  Uniquekey8
3         1112      us     13 round rd  Uniquekey7
4         1112      us   150 spring dr  Uniquekey2
5         1113      fr  26 chemin vert         NaN  # for testing

>>> match
                    0    1  2
1       123 nice road   92  1
2        97 square rd  100  8
3  13 round rd ste 10   90  7
4    150 spring drive   90  2
5       123 nice road   44  1  # for testing
```

Comment: @aero8991. Do you really need the fuzzy match score?

Comment: thank you again for your answer! I tried the .loc option and im getting a TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable. I thought maybe because it was that I had some NaN values in the unique key column so I did df1.dropna(subset = ['unique key'], inplace =True) however, im still getting the error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ok I think I understood. It's probably because the `score_cutoff`. If you have no response above THRESHOLD, the returned index is None. I'll check that

Comment: yeah that was it! I lowered the threshold to 10 and it worked. I wonder if theres a way to make it more accurate

Comment: Work in progress.

Comment: ah no my anaconda version is 3.7.4

Comment: @aero8991. I updated my answer. Now it should work even if a row does not match a unique key. If there is no match, the unique key is nan.

Comment: That did it! Thank you So much for your help this is really going to save me a lot of time at work. I really appreciate your help on this!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
df3 = pd.concat([df2, best_match.apply(pd.Series).drop(2, axis=1)], axis=1).rename({0:'unique key', 1:'fuzzy match %'}, axis=1)
```

Output:

```py
>>> df3
   index  cost-center country    address_df2          unique key  fuzzy match %
0      1         1111      us    123-nice-rd       123-nice-road             92
1      2         1111      us   97-square-rd        97-square-rd            100
2      3         1112      us    13-round-rd  13-round-rd-ste-10             90
3      4         1112      us  150-spring-dr    150-spring-drive             90
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this! I will test it and let you know. Can you please explain whats happening here?

Comment: Yes! Very simply, it's converting each match of `best_match` (each row of it) to a new `Series`. Then, it just annexes it to the left of `df2`. It also fixes up the column names. That's about as simple as it gets.

Comment: Got it thanks. So I actually wanted to pull in the uniquekey over from df1 **I thought that the best way to do this was to match on addresses, but I could be wrong** . Like for example the actual unique key for a row in my dataset is: "5892390u5198u7518"  but I just typed the words Uniquekey1, Uniquekey2 etc to simplify the example.  So for your output example, the first row's unique key id want the "Uniquekey1" value from df1 to be there. Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: Oh okay, let me see if I can do that for you...

Comment: @aero8991, will you please add your dataframes in dict for to the question? Get it like this: `print(df.to_dict())`. Because it's really hard to turn this text into a dataframe, and I need to again in order to continue working on this.

Comment: it looks like Corralien's method might work! Im testing it now. He has an interesting idea of making the matching process as a function and then locating the unique key within the other dataframe